# SQL/PHP - connection to database with php

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to setup a connection to my sql database based off the example below.

```
// ----------------------
// Retrieve some private information like my db password

   include("db_info.php");

// ----------------------
// Connect to Oracle database

   $conn = oci_connect('username', $db_pwd, '(DESCRIPT...
```

My question is, how do I handle the db_info.php file? I have my password stored in there as

```
$db_pwd = "something"
```

*Edit - The error I get when trying to open my page is as follows.

```
Array ( [code] => 24415 [message] => ORA-24415: Missing or null username. [offset] => 0 [sqltext] => )
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: When you use include(), all global variables from the included file should be immediately available for use. What is the error you're seeing? Does it have anything to do with the fact that your include() statement references a file ".db_info.php", and the text of your question references "db_info.php"?

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt I think the title is misleading and he is worried if anyone can read his password. So long as its out of the web root (public) folder its safe. In fact the only way it isn't safe (PHP being server-side) is if the PHP parser fails and the PHP file is displayed as plain text, which never happens.

Comment: Updated to show an error I am receiving.

Comment: Are you entering your correct username?

Comment: Yes. When I manually entered my password instead of using the $db_pwd I was able to connect. So the problem is likely with the include("../.db_info.php");

Comment: Figured it out, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your username is correct. If it's a variable in `db_info.php`, the code below is wrong:

```
$conn = oci_connect('username', $db_pwd, '(DESCRIPT...
```

if it's a variable it should be:

```
$conn = oci_connect($username, $db_pwd, '(DESCRIPT...
```

Also, are you sure you're using an Oracle database? (Sorry, had to ask) :)

EDIT:

Looking at this again, it looks like you have a simple typo. Try this:

```
include("../db_info.php");
```

You had an extra `.` in there.

Comment: Yes, I was able to connect when I manually entered my password. I would like to be able to use the include("../.db_info.php"); though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write in your database information somewhere, and your solution is sound enough. it doesn't even need to be hidden, since unless you have FTP-access, you'll never be able to view its content.